# AppRegistryNotReady ошибка при запуске проекта, что упустил?

Tags: django

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/alexey/Projects/doors7/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

 File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

File "/home/alexey/Projects/doors7/frontend/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    _('frontend')

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 83, in ugettext
    return _trans.ugettext(message)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 325, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 306, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

File "/home/alexey/door7_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
    "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "

**"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямо же и пишут: проверьте, что вы не используете не-ленивые вызовы gettext в корне модулей.

Comment: не хотел влезать в изменение файлов.т.к проект рабочий, пришлось смненить версию джанги на более старую и все заработало